Cassandra error with encoding during data import
i'm trying to import data from csv files according to notepad++ encoded in utf-8-bom to tables in cassandra4.0 and i'm getting error:
Starting copy of airportdb.airport with columns [airport_id, iata, icao, name].
airport.cql:44:Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 1 : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff1',  given up without retries

My import code:
CREATE TABLE airplane (
  airplane_id int  PRIMARY KEY,
  capacity int,
  type_id int,
  airline_id int
) ;

COPY airplane (airplane_id, capacity, type_id, airline_id)  
FROM 'airplane.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ';';

and how it csv looks like
CSVFile

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

cqlsh can't parse the BOM-encoded entries in your CSV file.
Save the file as just plain text then try again. Cheers!
